# PyQt: change the alignment of checkboxes in a QTableView

Tags: python, checkbox, pyqt, alignment, qtreeview

I have a `QTableView` with checkbox, but the checkbox is aligned left, and I need to align it center. I tried [this](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_project_org_faq#How_can_I_align_the_checkboxes_in_a_view.3F), but I have a problem with the "check" function:

```
def drawCheck(self, painter, option, rect, state):
    textMargin = QtGui.QApplication.style().pixelMetric(QtGui.QStyle.PM_FocusFrameHMargin) + 1
    checkRect = QtGui.QStyle.alignedRect(option.direction, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter, 
                 check(option, option.rect, QtCore.Qt.Checked).size(),
                QtCore.QRect(option.rect.x() + textMargin, option.rect.y(),
                option.rect.width() - (textMargin * 2), option.rect.height()))                           
    QtGui.QItemDelegate.drawCheck(self, painter, checkRect, state)
```

What is the "check" function? How can I reimplement the C++ example in PyQt?

Answer (score 0):

The example code you link to doesn't have a `check` function - could it be a typo that has been fixed? Or maybe it's a function defined in the code itself and isn't part of `Qt`?